# How do I fix my Spring Boot WebClient request. I receive the message as it is supposd but then I get an 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am trying to make a WebClient request against musicbrainz but do not understand what I am missing.
I have succeeded with resttemplate but when I try WebClient I succed but also fail.

I am using Spring Boot v2.5.0 and have not problem to start it.

My controller looks as following:

@RestController
public class MashupController {

```
@Autowired
private MashupService service;

@GetMapping("/{mbid}")
public Artist artistInfo(@PathVariable String mbid){
     
    Artist artist = new Artist();
    artist.setMbid(mbid);
    //MusicBrainz
    ArtistDetails artistDetailsResponse = MusicBrainzService.getArtistDetails(mbid);
    
    return artist;
```

}

This is just the first part and enough just to show the error.

I have an ArtistDetails class as following:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ArtistDetails {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Relation> relations;
    
    @JsonProperty("release-groups")
    private List<ReleaseGroup> releaseGroups;

... getters / setters
}
```

I have tried different setup and tried to find any solution but I am lost.

My service class looks as following:

```
public class MusicBrainzService {
    
    
    public static ArtistDetails getArtistDetails(String mbid){
        
        WebClient wc = WebClient.create("http://musicbrainz.org");
        
        
        ArtistDetails artistResponse = wc
                
                .get()
                .uri("/ws/2/artist/".concat(mbid).concat("?&fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups"))
                .retrieve()

//              .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> {
//                  System.out.println("4xx error");
//                  return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("4xx"));
//                })
//              .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, response -> {
//                  System.out.println("5xx error");
//                  return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("5xx"));
//                })
                
                .bodyToMono(ArtistDetails.class)
//              .retry()
//              .retryWhen(Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                .block();
                
        
        return artistResponse;      
    }
}
```

I have also tried with adding a ClientHttpConnector like the following.

```
private static ClientHttpConnector connector() {
    return new 
 ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection()));
}
```

As I wrote I still get an json reply as I am supposed but I also get

Response:

```
{"mbid":"5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da","description":null,"albums":[{"id":"fe317a1e-4339-4c45-86f4-229c33aa27ad","title":"Fully Illustrated Book & Interview Disc","image":null},{"id":"f1afec0b-26dd-3db5-9aa1-c91229a74a24","title":"Bleach","image":null},{"id":"1b022e01-4da6-387b-8658-8678046e4cef","title":"Nevermind","image":null},{"id":"2a0981fb-9593-3019-864b-ce934d97a16e","title":"In Utero","image":null},{"id":"01cf1391-141b-3c87-8650-45ade6e59070","title":"Incesticide","image":null},{"id":"5ab32af4-c62e-3cbf-aa8c-c761581d3b94","title":"Nirvana","image":null},{"id":"d4d28ec1-220a-327c-93c5-ae006be43598","title":"With the Lights Out","image":null},{"id":"e9674d41-d94b-344a-89f5-734736853d5f","title":"Sliver: The Best of the Box","image":null},{"id":"5cc5dc44-8860-462e-8aa5-2cf9b71af237","title":"ICON","image":null},{"id":"95563c6a-92e5-456c-9f86-6fe2ff1d148e","title":"2 for 1: Incesticide / In Utero","image":null},{"id":"55fca0ec-17ed-4860-b700-ef366574aa42","title":"Live! Tonight! Sold Out!!","image":null},{"id":"249e7835-5c39-3a10-b15b-e2d3470fb40c","title":"From the Muddy Banks of the Wishkah","image":null},{"id":"fb3770f6-83fb-32b7-85c4-1f522a92287e","title":"MTV Unplugged in New York","image":null},{"id":"48f5d526-0fa6-4ca6-ac59-9b2cf9ef464f","title":"Live at Reading","image":null},{"id":"e0372c5a-1750-46ec-8f1b-4b76df1fe8e7","title":"Live at the Paramount","image":null},{"id":"c171986d-83d9-4659-9644-ce9dc2b30836","title":"Live and Loud","image":null},{"id":"603761e1-7d54-41d3-b56b-f012a449f163","title":"Complete Live On KAOS FM 1987","image":null},{"id":"04f53329-d0d0-3b0d-856a-1e2cbcde0e69","title":"Love Buzz","image":null},{"id":"c01d417b-0e34-3723-9ebe-87de4620080c","title":"Sliver","image":null},{"id":"8c22577f-aaea-3973-9d27-20731751e088","title":"Candy / Molly’s Lips","image":null},{"id":"40f18565-ab15-3a93-8a9a-4ed6be9a112e","title":"Here She Comes Now / Venus in Furs","image":null},{"id":"03345972-d2f8-36bb-b49a-03a9ceccb7a7","title":"Smells Like Teen Spirit","image":null},{"id":"6970c348-86ce-3902-bee3-d2ebabc2643d","title":"Come as You Are","image":null},{"id":"be95ba52-8a66-3769-82ad-b5024e993ad7","title":"Lithium","image":null},{"id":"5d8050da-e5c9-3a1b-9e39-0a73620218c0","title":"In Bloom","image":null}]}
```

ErrorMessage:

```
2021-05-25 19:49:32.445 ERROR 708 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from GET http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/favicon.ico?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups] with root cause
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:213) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:259) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:401) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:416) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:470) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:685) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:94) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.7.jar:1.0.7]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[netty-codec-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at com.test.mashupmusicservice.service.MusicBrainzService.getArtistDetails(MusicBrainzService.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.test.mashupmusicservice.controller.MashupController.artistInfo(MashupController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.46.jar:9.0.46]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]



org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request from GET http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/favicon.ico?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:196) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 400 from GET http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/favicon.ico?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups [DefaultWebClient]
```

Using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Java 11

The error stack tells me that it is something wrong around ".block()" but I have not found any solution. Is it someone that can help me?

Comment: It looks *very like* `mbid == 'favicon.ico'` !!! (? ... the problem is in your path variable!; ...and the missing ressource handler!) (nice problem!+1)

Comment: ...but (probably) best & easiest solution (not to) and it is evidently bad practice *to use* a path variable (directly) *at the context root* (this could map/-tch anything! ..as `http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico`, which is probably issued by your browser.)

Comment: ..the problem could also "vanish" if you use a non-GUI/Rest-browser/curl (which doesn't request icons (scripts, resources, static content etc.))

Comment: Thank you @xerx593. How could I miss that!? If I instead make the uri equals to: .uri("/ws/2/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?&fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups")
It works fine. Do you know how I should initiate it instead of how I do to make it work with a parameter?

Comment: how about (just): `@GetMapping("/artist-info/{mbid}")` !? ;) ..and even better (path variables are tricky) `/foo/bar/{mbid}/do/something` (to avoid further conflicts)

Comment: @xerx593 THANK YOU! That worked perfectly and thanks for the good advices.

Comment: glad to help, bud! :) ...who makes it an answer first, gets the points!:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem **was**:

- You(r GUI-based browser internally) requested `http[s]://<yourhost>:<yourport>[/your-app]/favicon.ico`
- Your `@GetMapping("/{mbid}")` (`@PathVariable` at context root) overrides also (any default spring-web) `favicon.ico` handling, which results in `mbid == "favico.ico"` and the reported issue/behavior.

---

To overcome this, we could:

- use a REST-/not a GUI-based browser/[curl](/questions/tagged/curl). (That's quite restrictive!)
- (seems better) omit the conflict of your controller and (any spring default) static resource handling:

  - by overriding (introducing an extra controller for this) `@GetMapping("/favicon.ico")` (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon#gracefully-disable-favicon)
  - **(preferred)** Change the request path of your controller to something less ambiguous! :-) (e.g. `@GetMapping("/artist/{mbid}/info")`)